# VS Code reference types in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use an NPM package. In VS Code, I can use `/// <reference types ="@altv/types-server"/>` to give the IDE a hint as to where the file is located.
Is it possible to do this in WebStorm? If so, how?

Comment: What about trying it by yourself? WebStorm has a free trial version.

Comment: WS does understand `/// <reference types` in .ts file, it will be resolved to `node_modules/@types/<module name>/index.d.ts`

Comment: I installed WebStorm.
I also know what it does, but I would also like to know how/whether I can implement it in WS.